# How can I adjust the font size of this arxiv template?

Tags: fontsize, arxiv

I am submitting a paper for a small project and really like the arxiv template [found here on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/style-and-template-for-preprints-arxiv-bio-arxiv/fxsnsrzpnvwc). Unfortunately, the font size is a bit too small for my professor's eyes when printed. The only way I know how to adjust font size is with the `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` command, which doesn't work because of this command in the style document of the template:

```latex
% font sizes with reduced leading
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
 \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xipt
 \abovedisplayskip      7\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 5\p@
 \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus 3\p@
 \belowdisplayskip      \abovedisplayskip
 \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 3\p@
}
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\small}{%
  \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt\@xpt
  \abovedisplayskip      6\p@ \@plus 1.5\p@ \@minus 4\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@  \@plus 2\p@
  \belowdisplayskip      \abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus 2\p@   \@minus 2\p@
}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt\@xpt}
\renewcommand{\scriptsize}{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt}
\renewcommand{\tiny}{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt\@viipt}
\renewcommand{\large}{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{16}}
\renewcommand{\LARGE}{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{20}}
\renewcommand{\huge}{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{23}}
\renewcommand{\Huge}{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{28}}
```

As a new-to-latex researcher, I don't completely understand what's going on here. It seems like this is overriding the default behavior of the font sizing/spacing, so the document is still in "ten point" font when I make the `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`. If I comment the lines above, then the font becomes larger, but the spacing between headings and enum items becomes awful.

Is there a simple way to increase the font size of this template without destroying the beautiful spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
  \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt\@xiipt
```

and so on and so on. @xipt (like the @xpt it replaced) is a shorthand for certain font sizes. See more[at this answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46535/change-the-fontsizes-of-an-existing-documentclass)

To the Stackexchange community, sorry if the formatting here is all wrong, this is my first answer.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!